# Open Jquery dialog from inside Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my current javascript/ajax request. I'm trying to open a Jquery dialog from inside my `.append` my code follows:

```
for (var i in rows)
{
  var row = rows[i];          
  var id = row[0];
  var NewEdit = row[0];
  var PreviousEdit = row[1];
  var FunctionName = row[2];
  var FunctionID = row[2]
  function ShowInfo() 
  {
    dialog('Original: <br>'+PreviousEdit+'<br><br> New: <br>' +NewEdit);
  }
  $('#RecentEdits').append("<br>Page: <a href=Page.php?ID="+FunctionID+">"+FunctionName+"</a> - <a href='#' OnClick='ShowInfo()'>Info</a>");
}
```

I have only pasted relivant code, if required I can post the entire function.

I know for a fact, my variables are correctly set due to them being printed out.

How can I open up a Dialog box showing more information from inside a Javascript function?

---

**Solution:**

As there is no correct replies. I have used OQJF's example and produced this:

```
    <script>
function ShowInfo(a,b) 
      {
       alert('Original: \n'+unescape(a)+'\n\n New: \n'+unescape(b));
      };
    </script>
   <script>
//window.setInterval(function()
//{
  $(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'RecentUpdates.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
        {
        $('#RecentEdits').empty();

            for (var i in rows)
            {
                var row = rows[i];          
                var id = row[0];
                var NewEdit = row[0];
                var PreviousEdit = row[1];
                var FunctionName = row[2];
                var FunctionID = row[3];
                $('#RecentEdits')
                .append("<br>Page: <a href='Page.php?ID="+FunctionID+"'>"+FunctionName+"</a> - ");
                $('#RecentEdits').append("<input type='button' onClick=ShowInfo('"+escape(PreviousEdit)+"','"+escape(NewEdit)+"'); value='Show'>");
            } 
        } 
    });       
  });
// }, 1000);
  </script>
```

which has enabled me to access the function from my Javascript printout.

I had troubles with the quotes wrapped around my html  so i have decided to make two appends. And this seems to work just fine!

Comment: You had a non-standard function statment (not expression) in your code, pending edit done.

Comment: Cold I request that you post an answer and explain where i'm going wrong? I've only recently took up AJAX/Javascript so i'm still in the learning process

Answer (score 0):

While firstly I think you should set the function showInfo outside of the loop and set 2 parameter for it. Below is the sample code that I didn't test but It should be almost like this.

```
 function ShowInfo(orginVal,newVal) 
      {
        var msg =('Original: <br>'+orginVal+'<br><br> New: <br>' +newVal);
        $(<div>msg</div>).appendTo('body).dialog();//maybe you can add some options for dialog
      }
```

below part seems be in another function.

```
    for (var i in rows)
    {
      var row = rows[i];          
      var id = row[0];
      var NewEdit = row[0];
      var PreviousEdit = row[1];
      var FunctionName = row[2];
      var FunctionID = row[2]

      $('#RecentEdits').append("<br>Page: <a href=Page.php?ID="+FunctionID+">"+FunctionName+"</a> - <a href='#' OnClick='ShowInfo(/*add your 2 parameters here*/)'>Info</a>");
    } s
```

Comment: must be an error somewhere on that function/change because now i'm not getting any output

Comment: Changed it to just an `alert()` for testing purposes.. and i'm still not able to reach the function

Comment: It's just a sample that give you the idea of create dialog and show your info, you can test the code or change it to meet your requirement.

Comment: please show more code, so that we can help you, I think it's not a big problem.

Comment: Which I understand, but i've modified it to take no parameters, and just perform an alert and i'm still unable to reach this function

Comment: Then what can be appen to the element:RecentEdits, use firebug to check it.

Comment: Recent edits is just a `<div id='RecentEdits'></div>`  that's it

Comment: Okay, I've got it printing out an alert with 'test' and the function takes no parameters. how do i modify so I can input params through the  `onClick`

Comment: Output of firebug: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]  

ShowInfo(Notes About SQL Injection);

Add.php# (line 1, col 15)` -- is this something to do with the contents of the var?